Using SimpleXML XPath To Find 'Or' Conditional Value
I am working on expanding my current SimpleXML XPath to include an 'or' condition.
Here is the original (working) code below, without any 'or' condition.
$strXpathVar = "Scholarship/Research";
$xml_record_awards_honor_scope_teaching = $xml_award_honor_report_record[0]->xpath('a:AWARDHONOR[a:SCOPE="'.$strXpathVar.'"]');

I have 'hard coded' it like this (below) and it works:
$xml_record_awards_honor_scope_teaching = $xml_award_honor_report_record[0]->xpath('a:AWARDHONOR[a:SCOPE="Scholarship/Research" or "Teaching"]');

However, I am interested in how I can use $strXpathVar to be something like below.  This is not currently working, although I've tried altering the quotes in a number of ways:
$strXpathVar =  " ""Scholarship/Research" or "Teaching"" ";
$xml_record_awards_honor_scope_teaching = $xml_award_honor_report_record[0]->xpath('a:AWARDHONOR[a:SCOPE="'.$strXpathVar.'"]');

The simpleXML object $xml_award_honor_report_record is obtained before this step, by filtering on the username.
$xml_award_honor_report_record = $xml_award_honor_report->xpath('//a:Record[contains(translate(@username,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ","abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"),"'.$user_name.'")]');

Here's a fragment of the XML:
 <Record userId="14" username="CSmith9">       
    <AWARDHONOR id="25">
        <NAME>Instuction 2022</NAME>
        <SCOPE>Scholarship/Research</SCOPE>
     </AWARDHONOR>
    <AWARDHONOR id="23">
        <NAME>Instruction 2023</NAME>
        <SCOPE>Teaching</SCOPE>
    </AWARDHONOR>
 </Record>


A minimal sample of the XML fragment would help to understand the question.

You could use the contains approach in the opposite manner
enclosing the search-strings with a character from which you know that does not exist in those search-strings; like i.e. |.
$strXpathVar =  "|Scholarship/Research|Teaching|";

and also use that char to enclose the element-value like this
concat("|",A:SCOPE,"|"))]

Your statement would than look something like this:
xpath('a:AWARDHONOR[contains("'.$strXpathVar.'",concat("|",A:SCOPE,"|"))]')

Not tested.
